# Symfony - form type collection - how to PUT entities by ID

Tags: forms, symfony, one-to-many, jmsserializerbundle

I work on a Symfony project (an API) and it uses JSMSerializer, so every data sent as payload is in json format.

Then, I have two entities, say User and Devices. I have build two form types for each one, and while relationship between these two is OneToMany, in the first one's FormType, the 'devices' field is a collection of DeviceType forms.

When adding, is simple, you have to post something like this

```
{
  "user": {
    "name": "John",
    "devices": [
      {
        "os": "Android",
        "color": "red"
      },
      {
        "os": "Android",
        "color": "blue"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Everithing works just fine. Entities are persisted in db.

When updating, same payload can be sent, in that very same order, with some modified data, just like this

```
{
  "user": {
    "name": "John",
    "devices": [
      {
        "os": "Android",
        "color": "redish"
      },
      {
        "os": "Android",
        "color": "blueish"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and Symfony does its magic.

My problem is when order of the devices sent when updating changes. It causes all kind of problems.

My question is how can I send an ID of the elements in collection so symfony/doctrine maps it and knows who and how to update?

I thought of something like this

```
{
  "user": {
    "name": "John",
    "devices": {
      "2": {
        "os": "Android",
        "color": "blueish"
      },
      "1": {
        "os": "Android",
        "color": "redish"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

When you try to update an entity by persist, the instance you have currently is not attached to the entity manager. Then when you persist the entity, it creates another one.

If that appends, you need to add the id to the entity, and **merge** instead of **persist**.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#merging-entities

**Alternative solution:**

If you are making a request to update devices order in a list, maybe you should just send an array with new order, such as array(id => newOrder, ...), and load all devices owned by an user, update their order, and flush them.

In this solution, the order must be an entity attribute, integer. If it is not done yet, it should be

Comment: Well, when working with Form Types, when the form type is instantiated an instance of the entity is passed within the constructor. The entity passed (in this case User) to form type is found through some repository and therefore it and its related entities (in this case Device) are "known" to EntityManager. If you do some updates to those and perform a EntityManager::flush() you will see those updates in the database.

Comment: On the other hand, I think I have found a workaround. If no clean answer appears, I might post my solution. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: @Michael I know it's been a while but can you show me how you have made this work? I'm trying to achieve something similar.